# require username and password

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

*Please guide me accordingly if this question is noobish or a kind of duplicate.*

I am wondering how to implement this kind of authentication?

[image]

I am asking because I'm quite lost and doesn't know which keywords to search for this. On my mind, I am planning to have this whenever a user wants to access my domain (eg. http://mysite.com and http://mysite.com/tools).

Comment: Please state what webserver you are using, it will help alot :)

Comment: Hmm, I tagged Apache & PHP. Will that do?

Comment: looks like, you are searching for htaccess   http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml

Comment: Sorry missed that; found this tutorial: http://davidwalsh.name/password-protect-directory-using-htaccess

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The keywords you are looking for are: `htaccess`, `htpasswd`, `.htaccess`.
(Providing you use apache)

Ultimately you will put a `.htaccess` file in the dir you want to protect, and let it check the requirements with your `htpasswd`file.

For example: on my server I don't want people seeing my `private` directory.

```
$ sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd benjamin
```

**Note** that `benjamin` in the command above ^ is the username which we will use to log in.

We'd like the `.htpasswd` file outside our webfolder for some security.

Then in my `private` dir I'd put a `.htaccess` file that contains this:

```
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName Authenticate
AuthType Basic
require user benjamin
```

Comment: The benjamin here `htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd benjamin` is this the password?

Comment: @LeandroGarcia No, that is the username.

Comment: Does this applies to the subdirectories of your `private` dir (as based on your example), or just the root directory itself only?

Comment: @LeandroGarcia This should protect the subdirectories as well.

Comment: Thanks, pardon for my ignorance. Does this `.htpasswd` accepts hashed passwords? I mean, it can be a threat if the password is naked in `.htpasswd`, so I'm thinking if say the password is hashed in `sha1`, will the password I'll enter in the auth box be automatically hashed for checking? Or do I need to create a separate script for that?

Comment: @LeandroGarcia The password will be hashed and the hash will be saved into `.htpasswd`. [See the manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/htpasswd).

Comment: Thanks, I already implemented this. However, I noticed even if I clear the cache of my browser, it didn't ask for the credentials anymore. How does the credentials stored, via cookie? Is there any kind of timeout for expiration for that?

Comment: @LeandroGarcia I think they are stored via session but am not really sure.

Answer (score 1):

It is called HTTP Authentication

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Send `WWW-Authenticate` header to prompt for authentication

```
<?php header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');?>
```

The authentication credentials will be available in the following `$_SERVER` variables

Username - `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`
Password - `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`

Confirm the username and password and if they don't match, send `HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized` status to fail or send the `WWW-Authenticate` header again to prompt again.

As Benjamin mentioned, you could also use auth module

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html#gettingitworking

Comment: The idea of this site is to create a collection of useful Q&A posts that will be able to help visitors in the future. An answer (even if it's correct) that depends solely on a link is prone to link rot and if the URL dies, the answer will have lost it's worth. It's always better to provide an answer that can stand alone and provide a link for reference.

Comment: @Lix AFAIK httpd manual and php manual link structure hasn't changed in several years. But thanks, I will keep that in mind from next time.

Comment: Those specific links are pretty safe, I agree.  But with link only posts, you never know what weird corporate rules people have at work.  Sometimes people will be blocked from certain content.  That's why it's better to give the general idea and something helpful in addition to the link...